# Implement B-tree insert, delete

Tags: algorithm, b-tree

I'm learning how to insert/delete in B-tree.
And just find out that whenever I delete an element, then add it again. 
The result after adding is always the same of before deleting.
Is that's always true.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What is your question?

The exact layout of a B-tree is order dependant, so no, it will not necessarily be the same when your remove and re-add an element.

```
         5
        / \
 1 2 3 4   6 7 8

       4
      / \
 1 2 3   5 6 7 8
```

are both proper B-trees of order 2 for the same data, produced by different permutations of the insertions of numbers 1-8.